# xcode 6.2. view controllers greyed out, locked

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have a xcode project with buttons and other objects in it. But the objects are all greyed out in my view now. The project still compiles and shows the buttons fine. I saw posts about using auto-layout, changing size-classes, and modifying the IB. But whenever I make any of those changes, a lock icon shows on the screen and nothing changes. I can go back to an old version of my code, but I'd rather find out what will fix the issue.

What was I doing to break it? I was just exploring through the different xcode windows and views, and don't know exactly when the viewcontroller objects became affected.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally locked the views in IB. Go to the menu `Editor` then `Localization locking` and put it on `Nothing` if it's not the case.

Comment: ah, that seemed to do the trick, after putting 'nothing' in the localization locking, I was able to disable the size classes and get the views back back